# Running command line commands within Ruby script

Tags: ruby, command-line, scripting, terminal, command-prompt

Is there a way to run command line commands through Ruby? I'm trying to create a small little Ruby program that would dial out and receive/send through command line programs like 'screen', 'rcsz', etc.

It would be great if I could tie all this in with Ruby (MySQL backend, etc.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling shell commands from Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/calling-shell-commands-from-ruby)

Answer (score 223):

Yes. There are several ways:

---

**a.** Use `%x` or '`':

```
%x(echo hi) #=> "hi\n"
%x(echo hi >&2) #=> "" (prints 'hi' to stderr)

`echo hi` #=> "hi\n"
`echo hi >&2` #=> "" (prints 'hi' to stderr)
```

These methods will return the stdout, and redirect stderr to the program's.

---

**b.** Use `system`:

```
system 'echo hi' #=> true (prints 'hi')
system 'echo hi >&2' #=> true (prints 'hi' to stderr)
system 'exit 1' #=> nil
```

This method returns `true` if the command was successful. It redirects all output to the program's.

---

**c.** Use `exec`:

```
fork { exec 'sleep 60' } # you see a new process in top, "sleep", but no extra ruby process. 
exec 'echo hi' # prints 'hi'
# the code will never get here.
```

That replaces the current process with the one created by the command.

---

**d.** (ruby 1.9) use `spawn`:

```
spawn 'sleep 1; echo one' #=> 430
spawn 'echo two' #=> 431
sleep 2
# This program will print "two\none".
```

This method does not wait for the process to exit and returns the PID.

---

**e.** Use `IO.popen`:

```
io = IO.popen 'cat', 'r+'
$stdout = io
puts 'hi'
$stdout = IO.new 0
p io.read(1)
io.close
# prints '"h"'.
```

This method will return an `IO` object that reperesents the new processes' input/output. It is also currently the only way I know of to give the program input.

---

**f.** Use [`Open3`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open3/rdoc/index.html) (on 1.9.2 and later)

```
require 'open3'

stdout,stderr,status = Open3.capture3(some_command)
STDERR.puts stderr
if status.successful?
  puts stdout
else
  STDERR.puts "OH NO!"
end
```

`Open3` has several other functions for getting explicit access to the two output streams.  It's similar to popen, but gives you access to stderr.

Comment: Bonus trick: `io = IO.popen 'cat > out.log', 'r+'`; writes the command's outputs to "out.log"

Comment: What are the pro and cons for each. How do I decide which to use? How about using `FileUtils` [http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html] ?

Comment: I am executing a SVN command using exec. I don't want the output of exec to appear on the console. I want to redirect it so that I can store it as a variable and do some processing on this. How do I do it ?

Comment: status.successful? is no longer working for me on ruby 2.4, it changed to status.success? :)

Answer (score 14):

There's a few ways to run system commands in Ruby.

```
irb(main):003:0> `date /t` # surround with backticks
=> "Thu 07/01/2010 \n"
irb(main):004:0> system("date /t") # system command (returns true/false)
Thu 07/01/2010
=> true
irb(main):005:0> %x{date /t} # %x{} wrapper
=> "Thu 07/01/2010 \n"
```

But if you need to actually perform input and output with the command's stdin/stdout, you'll probably want to look at the [`IO::popen`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M002242) method, which specifically offers that facility.

Comment: popen works well if your app just has standard out. If you need more interaction or want to do something different with stdout, stdin, and particularly stderr you'll also want to look into open3: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Open3.html

Answer (score 7):

```
 folder = "/"
 list_all_files = "ls -al #{folder}"
 output = `#{list_all_files}`
 puts output
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is certainly doable but the method of implementation differs dependant on whether the  "command line" program in question operates in "Full screen" or command line mode. Programs written for the command line tend to read STDIN and write to STDOUT. These can be called directly within Ruby using the standard backticks methods and/or system/exec calls.

If the program operates in "Full Screen" mode like screen or vi then the approach has to be different. For programs like this you should look for a Ruby implementation of the "expect" library. This will allow you to script what you expect to see on screen and what to send when you see those particular strings appear on screen.

This is unlikely to be the best approach and you should probably look at what you are trying to achieve and find the relevant library/gem to do that rather than trying to automate an existing full screen application. As an example "[Need assistance with serial port communications in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167858/need-assistance-with-serial-port-communications-in-ruby)" deals with Serial Port communications, a pre-cursor to dialing if that is what you want to achieve using the specific programs you mentioned.

Comment: A simple version of Expect is available in Ruby using its built-in [Pty](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/pty/rdoc/PTY.html) module.

Answer (score 1):

The Most Used method is Using `Open3` here is my code edited version of the above code with some corrections:

```
require 'open3'
puts"Enter the command for execution"
some_command=gets
stdout,stderr,status = Open3.capture3(some_command)
STDERR.puts stderr
if status.success?
  puts stdout
else
  STDERR.puts "ERRRR"
end
```