# Recording network traffic for test driven development

Tags: java, ruby, linux, networking

I ruby there is great https://github.com/vcr/vcr gem, but works only with ruby HTTP libraries. Is there tool that can be used to record and play network traffic, but from system level, or at least in java?? If not, could you give me proof of concept how to create such tool (only for linux)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [TCPRelay](http://tcpreplay.synfin.net/) to play network packets captured in libpcap format.
If you are using a protocol like sip, you can use [Sipp](http://sipp.sourceforge.net/), other option is to use [mts-project](https://code.google.com/p/mts-project/).

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [betamax](https://github.com/robfletcher/betamax).  It's a port of VCR for the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

I use wireshark... which has a command line version called tshark.  you can install that on centos via yum install wireshark-gnome (wireshark will install the gui, but wireshark-gnome ads it to your /bin and gives you tshark.)

I use Jenkins CI to run all my tests... for example, I work with VOIP/SIP testing a lot... so I have a jenkins job that when run:

1. starts SIPP load to a server
2. starts tshark recording to a file

I use a command line param to keep thsark to running for a duration - however you can use a signal to stop tshark as well.

you can set tshark to do a packet capture and pick up everything, or filter just certain layers, like RTP only or SIP only, etc.

If you dont want to use Jenkins to manage this, you can call tshark programatically via Ruby or any scripting language... Just use Ruby to open and run the application... like: [Running command line commands within Ruby script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159945/running-command-line-commands-within-ruby-script)

Answer (score 0):

for Java. try [anystub](https://github.com/anystub/anystub). you could record/playback any invocation in your project