# Execute Ruby Gem from Ruby Script

Tags: java, ruby, shell, syntax, runtime-error

I have installed gem rvpacker gem. From command runs fine but I want to set its options. I have this method by now

```
def runPacker(dir, type)
  puts dir
  puts type
  begin
    rvpacker -V -f -d #{dir} -t ace -a #{type}
  rescue Exception =>e
    puts "Error!"
    puts e.message
    puts e.backtrace.inspect 
    return 1
  end
  return 0
end
```

How to write this rvpacker line by using my parameters?

It's the script which I will run from Java App by using JRuby.
When I call this command from JRuby directly I got

```
org.jruby.embed.ParseFailedException: (SyntaxError) <script>:1: syntax error, unexpected tUMINUS
rvpacker -V -f -d P:\temp-workspace\RPGTestProject1 -t ace -a unpack
```

But when I write it in console directly it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

`rvpacker -V -f -d #{dir} -t ace -a #{type}`
this is not ruby code and I wanted to execute it from ruby interpreter ;) Ave me!

Answer (score -1):

If I've understood your question right, then I think you'll find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159945/running-command-line-commands-within-ruby-script). For instance, you could wrap your command in a system call so that instead of the line:

```
rvpacker -V -f -d #{dir} -t ace -a #{type}
```

you would use

```
system "rvpacker -V -f -d #{dir} -t ace -a #{type}"
```

Comment: Please include relevant information from the link in your answer, or your answer may be deleted. You can keep the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @BrettWalker I hope that's enough to undo the downvote ?

Comment: It was not I who down voted. But thank you for improving your answer.

Comment: K, thanks ... obviously I'm still learning what's expected here.